# Ruby on rails 3: Search with multiple params?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search, where-clause

I have a search box, and need to search through 2 parameters, "title" or "tags" using the query. I can get one parameter to work, but not two, tried 'OR', '||', ',' nothing works.

Whats the answer ?

Original code: `Book.where("title LIKE ?" , "%#{query}%")`

What I need: `Book.where("title LIKE ?" , "%#{query}%" OR "tags LIKE ?" , "%#{query}%")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Book.where("title LIKE ? OR tags like ?" , "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
```

You should have the "full" SQL query first which contains the placeholders (`?`) as the first argument for the `where` query and then the remaining arguments are simply the replacements for the placeholders.

For more information please see the [Active Record Querying guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Great it works, and I now I understand the questionmarks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at `metawhere` which is dedicated to complicated queries (I know this one isn't but it worth noticing).

[See Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch).

Comment: consider +1 the answer then :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

```
Client.where("orders_count = ? AND locked = ?", params[:orders], false)
```